# Failed to resolve following three dependencies in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, dependencies, android-lifecycle, instantsearch

```
dependencies {
...

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'

//Lifecycle Extensions
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.1"

//VegaLayoutManager
    implementation "com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6"

//Algolia Search
    implementation "com.algolia:instantsearch-android:2.4.0"

...
}
```

When I add these three dependencies in build.gradle(Module) file of my project in android studio and sync it, I get 3 warnings of "failed to resolve" these three dependencies.

And when I run my project, I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.1/extensions-2.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.1/extensions-2.1.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.1/extensions-2.1.1.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.1/extensions-2.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/stone/vega/library/VegaLayoutManager/1.0.6/VegaLayoutManager-1.0.6.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/stone/vega/library/VegaLayoutManager/1.0.6/VegaLayoutManager-1.0.6.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/stone/vega/library/VegaLayoutManager/1.0.6/VegaLayoutManager-1.0.6.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/stone/vega/library/VegaLayoutManager/1.0.6/VegaLayoutManager-1.0.6.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.algolia:instantsearch-android:2.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/algolia/instantsearch-android/2.4.0/instantsearch-android-2.4.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/algolia/instantsearch-android/2.4.0/instantsearch-android-2.4.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/algolia/instantsearch-android/2.4.0/instantsearch-android-2.4.0.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/algolia/instantsearch-android/2.4.0/instantsearch-android-2.4.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I've checked for the versions of these dependencies, all the versions exist. I'm using them with kotlin version 1.5.0.
What does it mean by "dependencies not resolving" and how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please include text versions of the errors, without linking to external sites. Many users (eg. on mobile devices) can't see the images very well.

Comment: @exa I've included text versions of the errors

Answer (score 2):

Gradle looks at multiple repositories to find your dependency. In your case, it didn't find those in any of the repositories you declared in your `repositories` section.

You can check for available versions: [InstantSearch Android](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.algolia/instantsearch-android) or [Lifecycle](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=android.arch.lifecycle#android.arch.lifecycle:extensions)